# Find if lines are parallel, coincident or they intersect. If they intersect, find point of intersection

Tags: c, geometry, lines

I'm trying to create a program in which you input coefficients of two lines (a1x+b1 and a2x+b2) and it calculates if they are coincident, parallel or if they intersect, it finds the point of intersection. I can't successfully compare the coefficients and the output of the program is always like this: They intersect at point (0.00,0.00). What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

#define epsilon 0.001

int main() {

    float a1, b1, a2, b2;
    float x = 0;
    float y = 0;


    printf("Insert a1,b1,a2,b2: ");
    scanf("%f %f %f %f", &a1, &b1, &a2, &b2);
    if (fabs(a1 - a2) < epsilon && fabs(b1 - b2) < epsilon) {
        printf("Coincident");
    } else if (fabs(a1 - a2) < epsilon && fabs(b1 - b2) > epsilon) {
        printf("Parallel");
    } else if (((fabs(a1 - a2) > epsilon && fabs(b1 - b2) > epsilon) ||
            (fabs(a1 - a2) > epsilon && fabs(b1 - b2) < epsilon))) {
        x = (b2 - b1) / (a1 - a2);
        y = a1 * x + b1;
        printf("They intersect at point (%.2f, %.2f)", x, y);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce. If I enter `1 0 -1 3` it prints `(1.50 1.50)`.
And if I enter `2 1 -3 4` it prints `(0.60, 2.20)`.

Comment: That works correctly.

Comment: What *is* wrong is that you use wrong test for Parallel which should only compare the gradients `a1` and `a2`, since you already checked for Coincident. And there is unnecessary conditional test in the last section, since if the lines are not parallel they must intersect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[right demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ymMHz.png)

It is right.Maybe,your input is wrong.like this~[wrong demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tpnf8.png)

Comment: Good catch: suggest `if(scanf("%f %f %f %f", &a1,&b1,&a2,&b2) == 4) { ... }`. (But please post text, not images).

Comment: Please use code boxes and not images to represent code and input/output dumps.